# Jenkins: trending graph for build step time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My project has about 20 build steps and i want to monitor how much time each step takes over builds. I found Jenkins doesn't display such info.
Can use any of Jenkins tools or plugin to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was just looking for the same and found your post.  There is this plugin though it doesn't show you a nice graph or anything it will add the raw timestamps to your log lines on a per project basis. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper  If you install it you have to configure each project separately to check the add timestamps to console box (there is a script for doing all projects at once but I didn't want to chance that and only need it to diagnose a particularly slow build).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this. Makes sense to your case.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/build-metrics-plugin

Comment: this plugin show build time only, i need something more detail on each step